# How to load application.properties into Log4j2 LogEventPatternConverter class?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2, properties-file

I am working on a task that I want to mask sensitive data using Log4j2 LogEventPatternConverter Class.

```
@Plugin(name="SensitiveDataLog", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({"sense"})
public class SensitiveDataLog extends LogEventPatternConverter {

    @Value("${ssn}")
    private String ssn;

    public SensitiveDataLog(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static SensitiveDataLog newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new SensitiveDataLog("sense","sense");
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent logEvent, StringBuilder outputMsg) {
        String message = logEvent.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();
        Matcher matcher = SSN_PATTERN.matcher(message);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll("***-**-****");
            outputMsg.append(maskedMessage);
        } else {
            outputMsg.append(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to keep pattern in `application.properties`, But problem here is we cannot load property value `ssn`. Always its null.

Here is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" monitorInterval="30"
               packages="com.virtusa.xlab.fw.logging.component"
               xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">logs/log4j2</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- File Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="FILE"
                     fileName="${basePath}/logfile.log" filePattern="${basePath}/logfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %sense%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
        </RollingFile>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">

            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %sense%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.virtusa.xlab.fw" level="info" />
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **SensitiveDataLog** is created via static method **newInstance()**. Obviously, field ssn is not initialized at that moment. What you can do is to init the field later, e.g. when refreshing Spring context.
Here is my snippet:

```
private static XmlMaskPatternConverter INSTANCE = new XmlMaskPatternConverter();

public XmlMaskPatternConverter() {
    super(NAME, NAME);
}

public static XmlMaskPatternConverter newInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Now you can call static method **getInstance()** somewhere in your Spring Configuration (I do it in @Bean method) and set the **ssn** value there. Ofc, you need to create a setter for this field.

P.S. Hope it helps. I faced this problem too, so decided to leave my solution here. My first post on SO btw)